# Split a string in haskell: escape character '\' as delimiter

Tags: haskell, split, escaping

I am having a problem splitting a string with a '\' as a delimiter.
I copied this function:

```
  splitText :: String -> Char -> [String]

  splitText [] delim =[""]
  splitText (c:cs) delim
                  | c==delim = "" : rest
                  |otherwise = (c:head rest):tail rest
                  where
                    rest= splitText cs delim
```

the problem is: my string starts like this: "\sentence...." and I get the following error:

```
  lexical error in string/character literal at character 's'
```

I tried to escape the delimiter with '\' but it doesn't work.
I am allowed to use only modules that come pre-packaged with ghci /prelude

Comment: That code doesn't contain that error. What are you doing that results in the error? What exactly are you doing when you try to escape it?

Comment: Yes, that code works fine with other type of input. but if I call it like this: splitText  "\sentence number 1" '\' , it throws that error message. The problem is about splitting a text that has an escape character. So for example even the built-in function LINES "\sentence" will give the same error.

Comment: You need to escape both slashes: `splitText "\\sentence number 1" '\\'`. Also, when you're writing inline code, you should use backticks (\`) so that the StackOverflow formatter doesn't eat the `\\`s.

Comment: You're right. The problem I was testing this code directly in Prelude, and for some reason it won't recognize the '\\'. When I compile the function, it works. Thank you for your help

Comment: That should work both when running it in GHCi (I think this is what you mean by testing it in the Prelude) and when you compile it.